# Child Div Not Behaving

Tags: html

I'm making a website for an organization at my school, using basic HTML and CSS.  Right now, I've made several other pages for the site and have run into no problems like this one.

Here is the page I am having trouble with, if you want to view it in context:
http://acacians.net/scratch/officers-slim.html

I tried posting the code here, but it didn't completely work. I suggest following the link and viewing the source.

The final "officer" div is for some reason falling outside of my "info" div, which is nested in the "pagecontent" overall div.

Here is a link to the original CSS:
http://acacians.net/scratch/style.css

I'm really not sure what other information to supply, so I'll do my best to watch for any questions and do my best to respond accurately to them.

Thank you,
-Mike

Answer (score 1):

Put `<br style="clear: both;">` just before closing `.info` div.

Comment: I suspect you probably actually want to put it just before closing the `class="info"` div. To expand on why this is necessary, a div will usually expand to contain all the flowed content inside it. However, your `officer` class is floated, rather than flowed. By forcing some zero-size flowed content to appear below `officer`, you force the div to expand to include it.

Comment: Thanks! That really helped! I was trying to put it into my CSS under br { clear: both; } but it wouldn't work.  Any idea why?  For now I just put it in my HTML where you suggested, and it works beautifully.  Thank you so much!